# EXCEL VBA: Dynamic range in custom sorting

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm currently learning the art of VBA programming in Excel, but I've struck my head against a wall trying to figure out how to make my macro dynamic.

I'm trying to create a macro which is supposed to sort two columns (V & W). The V column is a list of names, and the W column is the number of stock-deals made, and I want to sort the names according to the number of deals made (Largest to smallest). The number of names(rows) will change every time I run the macro, which is why I need the range to be dynamic.

Here is my static code:

```
    Range("V5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Partner attribution").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Partner attribution").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("W5:W7"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Partner attribution").Sort
    .SetRange Range("V5:W7")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("V5").Select
```

I've tried solutions like referring to the row count function, but as the entire W column has formulas, the "blank" cells will end on top, and the names and number of deals end in the bottom.

I hope some of you has the skills to make my range dynamic!

Thanks :-)

Comment: This is the kind of thing an embedded table would help with. You can add and subtract rows then access the table body range directly to sort it based on your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanation inside the code comments :

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortColW()

Dim LastRow As Long

' always use fully qualified objects instead of Select
With Worksheets("Partner attribution")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row '<-- get last row in column "W"
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear

    ' use the LastRow variable to define the last row dynamically
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("W6:W" & LastRow), _
                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With .Sort
        .SetRange Range("V5:W" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. As mentioned; The sheet supports 250 partners, which means the W column has VLOOKUP formulas all the way down to W250. When I run your macro, the partners gets sortet, but they are being ranked as "less" than the blank cells (The VLOOKUP cells in column W, that are blank due to the lack of a name to look up). Thus the partner names moves to the bottom of the column (W250). Do you have a solution to this problem? Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @AVinther This is how the sort works, where do you want the Partners with blank number of sales to be ?

Comment: I would be alot easier if I was able to upload a pic, but I keeps saying error when I try. I'll try to explain: The V column is a list of partners (Which varies from around 10-50). These are hardcoded. The W column then lists the number of deals made (From VLOOKUP formulas). Because the sheet is a template, the list is made compatible for 250 partners, which means the W column has formulas all the way down to around W250-ish. I often have around 40 partners to rank by number of deals made. This leaves around 210 cells empty. When i run the macro, the 210 cells ranks higher, which moves

Comment: the partner names and the number of deals to the bottom. Because the names and number of deals links to other VLOOKUP formulas in the sheet, these are required to be on the top. That's why I want to sort the partner names according to the number of deals made, AND all the blank cells to be beneath them :-) Am I talking jibberish or is all this understandable? :-D

Comment: @AVinther for that have a "helper" column Y, put there a formula `=IF(ISBLANK(W2),1000000,W2)`, this will put a very high value in this cell. Then you can hide this column, and sort according to this column "Y" (which is hidden, and all blank values will be at the end),

Comment: Clever thinking! I managed to find a formula in another thread, which seems to do the trick!:

Sub SortColW()

Range("V5").Select
                                                                                
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                                      
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
                                   
Selection.Sort key1:=Range("W5", Range("W5").End(xlDown)),_
              
order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub

Comment: @AVinther again, read my answer, don't use `Select` and `Selection`, try to use fully qualified objects (it's safer, and faster)

Comment: I really am a noob when it comes to VBA. How would you correct the code? I've posted it as an answer (so the coding format is preserved). :-)

Comment: @AVinther this is not how the site really works, you are suppose to mark the nest answer from the user that helped you solve your error, not to post it as your own. Anyyway, not sure what is your current question

Comment: Alright. Did not know that. Thanks for your help though Shai! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the range dynamically

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row
Range("V5:W" & lastrow)
```

Comment: almost there... now you want to qualify the `Range` with `Worksheets("Partner attribution")` , and not use `Select`

Comment: Thanks Ashok! But as I wrote to Shai, the names are being moved to the bottom of the column, as the W column has formulas all the way to W250. The blank cells are then being ranked as "higher" than the cells with partners and number of deals, which places them on top. Do you have a solution/addition? Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @AVinther try this  it may be work for u `Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("W5"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues`

Answer (score 0):

@Shai Rado

I managed to find the following solution, which seems to do the trick! :-)

```
Range("V5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Sort key1:=Range("W5", Range("W5").End(xlDown)), _
order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```

Thanks though! :-)